# folder doesnt exist in Microsoft.NET\Framework

Tags: c#

so i was trying to run a c# file I copied from another website and i did

```
csc file.cs
```

the console was like:

```
'csc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

then i searched up where was csc.exe, and i found it was in
`Microsoft.NET/Framework/ folder`
but when i did [windows]+[r] and typed in Microsoft.NET,
it shows 2 framework files. `Framework` and `Framework64` i checked both files and the only exe file was NETFXSBS10.exe in Framework.

there was no csc.exe so i run NETFXSBS10.exe and nothng happend

Comment: Why are you trying to directly use the C# compiler rather than more comprehensive tools like MSBuild.exe?

Comment: @gunr2171 Not so sure that `dotnet.exe` will work for .NET Framework!

Comment: You need to use the "Developer Command Prompt for VS" to use `csc` natively.

Comment: Firstly, you will need to make sure that you have installed the .NET Framework SDK not just the runtime

Comment: Not true.  You can run csc from the command line, as long as you know all the parameters you wish to include, the proper switches  and the files to be compiled.   To be sure, it's a very messy way of doing things, so you'd be better if you could use Visual Studio or Visual Studio Code.  I've run csc before using a batch file.

Comment: what is the developer command prompt

Comment: where do i install the SDK

Comment: it doesnt work for me @TC_Guy

Comment: @gleacc do you have dotnet framework installed on your system?

Comment: if you look under c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319, you should see csc.exe, which is the C# compiler.  You would need to add the path to your Windows path  to be able to simply type 'csc' from any command prompt.  If not then you'd have to navigate to this folder in your command window and then type 'csc', or use the entire path from the command prompt to launch it.  You don't need to install anything to be able to use csc.exe, because the framework is installed automatically as part of Windows.  If you want a newer version than the default then you'd need to do that on your own.

Comment: last time i tried making java to path but it didnt work but i would try

Comment: YES IT WORKED   i used the path="C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe" and i did set path="C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe"